# Binning a numeric variable

Tags: r, binning

I have a vector X that contains positive numbers that I want to bin/discretize.  For this vector, I want the numbers [0, 10) to show up just as they exist in the vector, but numbers [10,∞)  to be 10+.

I'm using:

```
x <- c(0,1,3,4,2,4,2,5,43,432,34,2,34,2,342,3,4,2)
binned.x <- as.factor(ifelse(x > 10,"10+",x))
```

but this feels klugey to me.  Does anyone know a better solution or a different approach?

Comment: What's kludgy about that? It looks pretty neat to me.

Comment: @Rob: The main drawback of this approach is that you don't get factor levels created for values that aren't there (e.g., for this data there is no level "6"). This could be fixed with explicit levels in the call to `factor`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about `cut`:

```
binned.x <- cut(x, breaks = c(-1:9, Inf), labels = c(as.character(0:9), '10+'))
```

Which yields:

```
 # [1] 0   1   3   4   2   4   2   5   10+ 10+ 10+ 2   10+ 2   10+ 3   4   2  
 # Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10+
```

Comment: That seems more complicated than the solution in the question.

Comment: Minor improvements: Swap `1e6` with `Inf`.  You don't need `include.lowest=TRUE`.  (Compare answers by calling `table(binned.x)`.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, I can't say I disagree :)
@Richie: Thanks! I'm still learning the language, so your "minor improvements" are a major help to me.

Answer (score 7):

You question is inconsistent.
In description `10` belongs to "10+" group, but in code `10` is separated level.
If `10` **should** be in the "10+" group then you code should be

```
as.factor(ifelse(x >= 10,"10+",x))
```

In this case you could truncate data to 10 (if you don't want a factor):

```
pmin(x, 10)
# [1]  0  1  3  4  2  4  2  5 10 10 10  2 10  2 10  3  4  2 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x[x>=10]<-"10+"
```

This will give you a vector of strings. You can use `as.numeric(x)` to convert back to numbers ("10+" become `NA`), or `as.factor(x)` to get your result above.

Note that this will modify the original vector itself, so you may want to copy to another vector and work on that.